# asking the user to input numbers and then counting them and finding the average

Tags: java, if-statement, sum, average, counting

I need to write a code that takes the users input of numbers and adds them, displays the amount of positives, negatives, zeroes, and the count of the amount of numbers inputted once the user enters the letter 'e'.

When i enter 'e' though, the program terminates without printing the count or average.

Also, the average doesn't work because it says i cannot divide by zero.

```
    public static void main (String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int negative = 0;
        int positive = 0;
        int zeroes = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        int count = 1;
        int average = sum / (count - 1);

         do{
                System.out.print("Enter a float or 'e' to exit");
                String entered = input.nextLine();
                if("e".equals(entered)){
                    //print stuff
                    break;
                }else{
                    int num;
                    try {
                        num = Integer.parseInt(entered);
                    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                        System.out.print(negative + positive + 
                    zeroes + sum + (count - 1) + average);
                        continue; // re-do the loop
                    }
                    if(num  < 0){ 
                        sum += num;
                        count++;
                        negative++;
                    }else if (num > 0){ 
                        sum += num;
                        count++;
                        positive++;
                    }else{//similar to comment above
                        sum += num;
                        count++;
                        zeroes++;
                    }

                }
            } while(true);   
    }
}
```

Comment: When you try and compute the average, `int average = sum / (count - 1);`, your `count` variable is `1`. So you are dividing by `0` here.

Comment: It looks like your comment: `//print stuff`is on the right track, just put the code to print out the answer there.  (and move the average calculation to the print out location as @gonzo suggests)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the print in "if" condition. Modify the if condition as follows

```
if("e".equals(entered)){
  //print stuff
   System.out.print(negative + positive + zeroes + sum + (count - 1) + average);
  break;
}
```

As others people have commented, you need to consider cases like "divide by zero" and also handle input validation.